# Swift: AttributedString underline with different color

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, attributedstring

I'm trying to give different color for underlined text in the AttributedString. as per this example.

[image]

But the result with this snippet of code:

```
        var attributedString = try AttributedString(markdown: self)
        if let rangeWord = self.slice(from: "[", to: "]") {
            let range = attributedString.range(of: rangeWord)!
            attributedString[range].underlineStyle = .single

            attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .white
            attributedString[range].underlineColor =  .green

        }
```

Is not what is expected

[image]

Is there a workaround it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `NSAttributedString` likewise:

```
let labelString = "your label"
let textColor: UIColor = .black
let underLineColor: UIColor = .green
let underLineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue

let labelAtributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]  = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: underLineStyle,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: underLineColor
]

let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: labelString,
                                                   attributes: labelAtributes)

label.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the `uiKit` scope.

```swift
var attributedString = try AttributedString(markdown: self)
if let rangeWord = self.slice(from: "[", to: "]") {
      let range = attributedString.range(of: rangeWord)!
      attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .white

      // notice the "uiKit" addition 
      attributedString[range].uiKit.underlineColor = .green 
      attributedString[range].uiKit.underlineStyle = .single
}
```